Proving $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k! \, (2k)! \, (25k - 3)}{(3k)! \, 2^k} = \frac{\pi}{2} $
Wikipedia claims that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k! \, (2k)! \, (25k - 3)}{(3k)! \, 2^k} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
but does not give a citation. How can this be proved?
Edit: This was correctly closed as a duplicate, but the linked question in the duplicate message does not provide an answer. One is here.

See post 4 here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1429676p8053962. The generating function $F(x)$ that @tintarn uses is precisely what is needed here.

I believe there are several duplicates. see Approach0
